# Making Virtual Box work on a compiled kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kernel

I am trying to run a vm with virtual box and am getting the following error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>   The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing
>   '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>   as root.
>   where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

On executing `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` this is what I get:

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
>   vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
>   vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>   vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.
>   There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
>     /sbin/vboxconfig
>   as root.

Contents of `/var/log/vbox-setup.log`:

> Building the main VirtualBox module.
>   Error building the module:
>   make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-rc4/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
>   make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
>   Makefile:213: ================= WARNING ================
>   Makefile:214: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
>   Makefile:215: 
>   Makefile:216: If you are building an individual subdirectory
>   Makefile:217: in the kernel tree, you can do like this:
>   Makefile:218: $ make path/to/dir/you/want/to/build/
>   Makefile:219: (Do not forget the trailing slash)
>   Makefile:220: 
>   Makefile:221: If you are building an external module,
>   Makefile:222: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
>   Makefile:223: ==========================================
>   make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 need-modorder=1
>   /tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:141: *** Error: unable to find the headers of the Linux kernel to build against. Specify KERN_VER= (currently 5.3.0-rc5+) and run Make again.  Stop.
>   Makefile:1624: recipe for target '*module*/tmp/vbox.0' failed
>   make[1]: *** [*module*/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
>   /tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.footer:101: recipe for target 'vboxdrv' failed
>   make: *** [vboxdrv] Error 2

As I understand this is due to the script not being able to find the headers of my kernel.
This might be due to the fact that I have compiled my own kernel.
I would be glad to know what is actually going on here and how to fix it subsequently.

Comment: IIRC VBox depends on a module which is recompiled to match installed kernels. This is done using [DKMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support).